# How to pass long content of data which is in textarea to a servlet?

Tags: javascript, servlets

I have a large content of Data in a textarea (letters, digits and other characters) and allowed length to 4000. I passed its content by `document.getElementByID('txtarea').value;` to  another servlet.
Can I use `request.getParameter("pname")` method to get the large content of data to my servlet ?
If it is not how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes You can.

Make sure Your Field is under form element and you should use  `method=POST`.

Comment: What do you mean by Non Complex?Explain it.